# How can you get the data about the clicked object?

Tags: java, python, operating-system

I am thinking in creating an application, that would measure how much time are we spending on certain files or directories. For now, I haven't written any piece of code, I was just thinking about it.

Lets say, that the user left clicks icon of some random directory on the desktop. In order to display the content of the directory, the operating system should first identify what is located at click's location.

Or maybe if the internet browser is opened and you press exit button (top right corner) the operating system terminates the right process - not any other one.

In every case the operating system knows what exactly are you clicking, so there must be some mechanism how to do this, I just don't know how to reach it.

So my question is, **how to get the data about the clicked object** (path, type, pointer to the memory and stuff like that)?

I already know how to detect double click and it's location. I am planning to write the code in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the JAVA solution, i dont know Phython good enought but it may helps as the Question is tagged with JAVA

```
JButton btn = new JButton();
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void onActionPerformed(ActionEcent event){
         JButton btn = (JButton)event.getSource();
    }
});
```

You can do this with every `JComponent` and every listener, so if you do this with for example an `JLabel` and you add a `MouseAdapter` or `MouseListener` you allways can call getSource() to get the component which encountered the Event.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough... I need this for all windows that are generated by the os, not by my application. For example, if you open a folder, one window will appear (with folder's content), which is generated by the os. I need to get the data about that folder when you click close window (or open it).

Comment: Ok what you need, (I am quite sure) is a C language (++,#) because this is a platform depended and very complex task.Maybe it is simply not possible.

Comment: What maybe is possible is that you can "ask" about running processes get the PID (This is maybe possible in Java and Python) and try to communicate with them (i think therefore you need C++ , C or maybe C# also works but i am sceptic about this)

Comment: yes it works with PID... The only problem is, that this only works for processes and not also for opening the folder for example. I will try to find something, thanks a lot!

Comment: I think what you search is an Interface for the windows explorer.exe.
Look if there is any API with which you can catch some open folder events. But as i said allready i think if somethinkg like this exist ,it only will work with c/C++.
And maybe if you invetigate a bit , it is possible that the if you open an folder this sarts a new explorer process. Try it out. In the windows task manager there is an option to see all processes. If you are lucky explorer  starts a new child process (whith an own PID) for each open folder.

Comment: And please accept my answer. Also if I answered the question in the comment section